# What is the "living shroud" in Sarojini Naidu's "Dirge"?

Tags: poetry, sarojini-naidu

The third stanza of Sarojini Naidu's "[Dirge](https://en.m.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Bird_of_Time/Songs_of_Love_and_Death/Dirge_%E2%80%94_In_sorrow_of_her_bereavement)" goes like this:

> Shatter her shining bracelets, break the string
> Threading the mystic marriage-beads that cling
> Loth to desert a sobbing throat so sweet,
> Unbind the golden anklets on her feet,
> Divest her of her azure veils and cloud
> Her living beauty in a living shroud.

The stanza continues from the previous ones about the clothes, makeup, and jewelry of this new widow. However, then the stanza ends with "her living beauty in a living shroud".
The "living beauty" makes sense, but I'm confused what "in a living shroud" is supposed to be here. We've just described the finery and everything that she has, which isn't "living". What's going on here?

Answer (score 8):

Traditional Hindu culture uses clothing and jewellery to mark a woman's marital status. Married women wear bangles of red or green glass, bracelets of gold or conch shell, and/or a [*ma.ngalasuutra*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mangala_sutra), a gold necklace with black beads. There is of course much regional variation. For example, a *ma.ngalasuutra* is not customary in Bengal, whereas a shell bracelet is. And women from more cosmopolitan backgrounds may not feel the need to signal their marital status via their choice of clothing or accoutrements. But in much of the country it is typical to have some such markers of the woman's status as a wife, and they're also typically understood across communities. A Bengali person would readily know the significance of a *ma.ngalasuutra*, for example.

These markers all removed if the woman's husband dies. As Naidu's poem describes, the necklace and bangles are typically broken and discarded. Another custom, rather less prevalent now than it used to be, is that the widow also gives up colored clothing and wears all white. White garments are associated with death and funerals throughout South Asia: the corpse is clothed in white, and the funeral attendees wear white as well. Shrouds are also white.

Naidu makes the connection between the white clothing typical of widows and a white shroud. The widow is clad in white as in a shroud, but because she is alive, she is wearing a "living shroud".

Comment: Any reason you've added periods in _mangal sutra_?

Comment: @CDR I'm transliterating using [iTrans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ITRANS) coz it uses only ASCII characters. I could use [IAST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Alphabet_of_Sanskrit_Transliteration) and type  *maṅgalasūtra*, using diacritics instead of periods and doubled vowels, but that would require switching keyboard layouts, and I'm too fucking bone-idle.

Comment: @verbose you can use a simple "mangalsutra" instead, most Indians write it that way (see, e.g., pages for maglasutras on major jewellery stores like [Tribhovandas Bhimji Zaveri](https://www.tbztheoriginal.com/products/collections/mangalsutra) or [Tanishq](https://www.tanishq.co.in/shop/mangalsutra?lang=en_IN)).

Comment: @muru sure I can, but I tend to transliterate exactly rather than approximately. That seems advisable when writing for an audience unfamiliar with Devanagari (or allied scripts such as Bengali) or with terms like "ma.ngalasuutra". But tbh, it's just a quirk. I use iTrans when referencing Hindi film songs too: abhii na jaao chho.Dakar, ke dil abhii bharaa nahii.n. Or classical ba.ndish: saa.De naal ve miyaa.N dilabarayaa, sajan miyaa.N ramazaa.N. iTrans is so habitual with me, when asked what "sharada" meant, I said it was a season before I realized the asker meant "shaaradaa".

Comment: @verbose your post, your way, but I wonder if "ma.ngalasuutra" is helping _anybody_ other than those who are _both_ unfamiliar with Devanagari, etc. and familiar with this ASCII-only iTrans output.

Comment: @muru that is a philosophical question. I err on the side of precise rather than approximate transliteration, except for words that have become normalized in English: raga rather than raaga, Krishna rather than kR^iShNa. I think "ma.ngalasuutra" is not yet normalized, at least not in the US. I know too many people, even in India, who have no idea how to pronounce the name of the character Salya in the Mahabharata (सल्य ? साल्य ? शाल्य ? etc., none of these are correct) to trust approximate transliterations.